# How to get weighted median where $w_i$ is real?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, descriptive-statistics, median

I'm trying to get what Friedman's meant with "is the weighted median with weights wi", I know if $w_i$ is natural number I should to replicate each observation $w_i$ times and calculate the median of new sample with replicated values but i dont have any idea what i should do if $w_i \in \Re$.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to think about this is via the cumulative distribution  function, because it's all  just means and weighted sums are easy.

The unweighted empirical CDF is
$$\mathbb{F}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I(x_i\leq x)$$
and the weighted version is
$$\mathbb{F}_w(x)=\frac{1}{n_w}\sum_{i=1}^n w_iI(x_i\leq x)$$
where $n_w=\sum_i w_i$

The unweighted median is where the graph of $\mathbb{F}(x)$ crosses $y=1/2$; the weighted median is where that happens for $\mathbb{F}_w(x)$.  And, finally, that gives the definition of the weighted median as the smallest number $m$ such that $$\sum_{x_i\leq m} w_i \geq \frac{n_w}{2}$$

Comment: Is it shouldn't be $\sum_{x_i\leq m}w_i\leq n_w/2$? If you know any book or article that defines weighted median like this please tell me I would like look through on them.

Comment: You could use the largest $m$ such that the sum is less than or equal. As usual, there's more than one way to define the median.  THere's the wiki page and its references (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median) and the usual survey-sampling references is Woodruff RS (1952) *Confidence intervals for medians and other position measures.* JASA 57, 622-627.

Comment: @thomas_lumley Vazler et al. (2012) define as follows:

$u$ is any weighted median if $\sum_{y_i<u} w_i\leq n_w/2$ and $\sum_{y_i>u} w_i\leq n_w/2$ that is $u$ the data split weight data in a half. Are both approaches equivalent?

Comment: No, like the choices of how to define an unweighted median they differ, but by an amount that's small compared to the standard error.